# Convergence of moments independent of specific element $x_0$ when paired with weak convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Notation:** Let $(E,d)$ be a Polish space (separable and complete w.r.t. $d$). We say that a probability measure $\nu$ has finite first moment, if
$$ \int_E d(x,x_0)\nu(dx)<\infty $$
for some $x_0 \in E$ and then, by the triangle inequality,
$$ \int_E d(x,y_0)\nu(dx)\le\int_E d(x,x_0)\nu(dx)+d(x_0,y_0)<\infty $$
for all $y_0\in E$.

**Question:** Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \mu$ be probability measures on $E$ with finite first moment. Suppose
$$\int_E d(x, x_0)\mu_n(dx) \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_E d(x,x_0)\mu(dx) \qquad (*)$$
for some $x_0\in E$ and $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ (i.e. $\int_E f d\mu_n \longrightarrow \int_E fd\mu$ for all bounded, continuous $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$). Does $(*)$ then hold for all $x_0\in E$?

**Own work:** Let $y_0\in E$. Then
$$ \int_E d(x,y_0)\mu_n(dx)\le\int_E d(x,x_0)\mu_n(dx)+d(x_0,y_0),$$
so $\limsup_n \int_E d(x,y_0)\mu_n(dx) \le \int_E d(x,x_0)\mu(dx)+d(x_0,y_0)$. Since $d(x,y_0) \ge d(x,x_0)-d(x_0,y_0)$, we also $\int_E d(x,x_0)\mu(dx)-d(x_0,y_0)\le \liminf_n \int_E d(x,y_0)\mu_n(dx)$, which is a dead-end (?)
Different approach:
$$ \int_E d(x,y_0)\mu_n(dx) - \int_E d(x,y_0)\mu(dx) \le \int_E d(x,x_0)\mu_n(dx) - \int_E d(x,y_0)-d(x_0,y_0)\mu(dx), $$
and now I'd like to continue with $d(x,y_0)-d(x_0,y_0)\ge d(x, x_0)$, but the opposite is true. I know this should be easy but I don't see it, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

[The question has been edited after I posted thsi answer]

This is false. For a counter-example take $\mu_n=\delta_{-1}, \mu=\delta_1$ and $x_0=0$. The conclusion fails for $y_0=1$.

[Note that $\int f(x) \mu (dx)=f(z)$ if $\mu=\delta_z$].

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think it is correct if in addition we assume $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly? (I edited the post.)